# Read PPT file in PHP

Tags: php, slider, powerpoint

I would like to read all pages of PPT file and want to convert it into a one single slider that I can move next & previous through the button in PHP.

Please help me out!

Comment: http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/

Comment: check [here](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/php-libraries-for-working-with-excel-word-and-powerpoint-files/)

Comment: Unzip them, read the xml data as you want.

Comment: PHPPowerpoint doesn't support reader functionality... is there any otherway ?